# Overloading subscript operator on vector<int> and vector<bool> differences

Tags: c++, vector, boolean, operator-overloading

I am trying to implement bitset operators on a vector< bool> wrapper class.

My question is why the subscript operator [] works when the vector is an int, but not when it's a bool.

```
struct bitsetI {
    vector<int> data;
    bitset(int length) { data = vector<int>(length);}
    int &operator[](const int index) { return data[index]; }
}

struct bitsetB {
    vector<bool> data;
    bitset(int length) { data = vector<bool>(length);}
    bool &operator[](const int index) { return data[index]; }
}
```

With bitsetI

```
bitsetI I(4);
I[0] = 1;
```

is valid, but

```
bitsetB B(4);
B[0] = true;
```

won't compile, giving an "initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue" error.

I know that vector is an awkward specialization of vector (implementing this because I need to be able to declare bitstring lengths at runtime, not compile as with std::bitset, and speed is not an issue), but can't figure out what the problem is here, and if there's a work-around or if I should just use a set function instead.

Comment: Look at what `std::vector<bool>::operator[]` returns.

Comment: "if there's a work-around" - return `std::vector<bool>::reference` instead of `bool&`.

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing this out chris, sometimes it's just right under your nose.